# Compiling Stellar-core on windows: where does mingw/cygwin come in

Tags: compiling, stellar

I am trying to compile stellar-core code on windows but I can't to figure out what to do with mingw to make it work. I.e. I have downloaded and installed all required tools including mingw but I don't know how to setup mingw to work here.

The install.txt says mingw is required for building xdrc but there isn't much more. When I tried to build is 2 out of 7 projects compiled successfully.

All tips will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure StackExchange is the place to ask this as it's issue level (which GitHub can take care of - https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues).

Anyways, in the Install-Windows.txt it says to also update your PATH environment variable, did you do this?